# Aligning 3 divs to certain width and height

Tags: html, css, alignment

i'm really not that good with html/css but i try my best to achieve the results i want. i'm creating an online resume for me adapting a source code i downloaded but i'm having some trouble making it the way i want.

this is how i was hoping it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozuEs.jpg

this is how it looks right now: http://fernandocysneiros.com/contrate

i dont know what i'm doing wrong. can anyone please help me? i searched before asking but got no luck. i'll paste the css and the header html here.

***css:***

```
<style>

    img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

    .msg { padding: 10px; background: #222; position: relative; }
.msg h1 { color: #fff;  }
.msg a { margin-left: 20px; background: #408814; color: white; padding: 4px 8px; text-decoration: none; }
.msg a:hover { background: #266400; }

/* //-- yui-grids style overrides -- */
body { font-family: Georgia; color: #444; }
#inner { padding: 10px 80px; margin: 80px auto; background: #f5f5f5; border: solid #666; border-width: 8px 0 2px 0; }
.yui-gf { margin-bottom: 2em; padding-bottom: 2em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }

/* //-- header, body, footer -- */
#hd { margin: 2.5em 0 3em 0; padding-bottom: 1.5em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc }
#hd h2 { text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; }
#bd, #ft { margin-bottom: 2em; }

/* //-- footer -- */
#ft { padding: 1em 0 5em 0; font-size: 92%; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; }
#ft p { margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center;   }

/* //-- core typography and style -- */
#hd h1 { font-size: 260%; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px; }
h2 { font-size: 152% }
h3, h4 { font-size: 122%; }
h1, h2, h3, h4 { color: #333; }
p { font-size: 100%; line-height: 18px; padding-right: 3em; }
a { color: #990003 }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
strong { font-weight: bold; }
li { line-height: 24px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
p.enlarge { font-size: 144%; padding-right: 6.5em; line-height: 24px; }
p.enlarge span { color: #000 }
.contact-info { margin-top: 7px; }
.first h2 { font-style: italic; }
.last { border-bottom: 0 }


/* //-- section styles -- */

a#pdf { display: block; float: left; background: #666; color: white; padding: 6px 50px 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 6px; text-decoration: none;  }
a#pdf:hover { background: #222; }

.job { position: relative; margin-bottom: 1em; padding-bottom: 1em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
.job h4 { position: absolute; top: 0.35em; right: 0 }
.job p { margin: 0.75em 0 3em 0; }

.last { border: none; }
.skills-list {  }
.skills-list ul { margin: 0; }
.skills-list li { margin: 3px 0; padding: 3px 0; }
.skills-list li span { font-size: 152%; display: block; margin-bottom: -2px; padding: 0 }
.talent { width: 32%; float: left }
.talent h2 { margin-bottom: 6px; }

#srt-ttab { margin-bottom: 100px; text-align: center;  }
#srt-ttab img.last { margin-top: 20px }

.perfil {
    display: block; 
    float: left;
    height:130px;
    overflow:visible;
    margin-bottom: 2em; 
    padding-bottom: 2em; 
    border-bottom: 1px 
}

/* --// override to force 1/8th width grids -- */
.yui-gf .yui-u{width:80.2%;}
.yui-gf div.first{width:12.3%;}

</style>
```

***html:***

```
<body>

<div id="doc2" class="yui-t7">
    <div id="inner">

        <div id="hd">

        <div class="yui-u">
                <div class="perfil" height="130px" vertical-align="center">
                    <h1>FERNANDO</h1>
                    <h1>CYSNEIROS</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="perfil" height="130px" vertical-align="center">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9qTYVst.jpg">
                </div>


                    <div class="perfil">
                        <table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><font color="#cccccc"><i><b>telefone</b></i></font></td>
    <td align="left">+55 (81) 8173-8769</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><font color="#cccccc"><i><b>e-mail</b></i></font></td>
    <td align="left">me@fernandocysneiros.com</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right"><font color="#cccccc"><i><b>linkedin</b></i></font></td>
    <td align="left">linkedin.com/in/fcysneiros</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td align="right"><font color="#cccccc"><i><b>portfólio</b></i></font></td>
    <td align="left">fernandocysneiros.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
                    </div><!--// .contact-info -->

            </div><!--// .yui-gc -->
        </div><!--// hd -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add these styles at the bottom of your template's stylesheet:

```
.perfil:first-child {
     width: 370px;
}

#hd h1 {
     font-size: 450%;
}

.perfil:nth-child(2) {
     margin: 0px 25px;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! it solved my problem :) i had to adjust a few things with the table and the proportions of everything but its all good now! thanks a lot!